# Fedora OpenJDK Set JAVA_HOME

Tags: linux, environment-variables, fedora, java

I am using Fedora(actually Pidora since I am trying to set up hadoop on a cluster of raspberrypi). I installed oopenjdk on all of the nodes using ansible. However, when I tried to set up the JAVA_HOME environment variable, I got really confused looking at the folder of `/usr/lib/jvm`:

```
[root@datafireball1 jvm]# ls
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.arm  jre  jre-1.7.0  jre-1.7.0-openjdk  jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.arm  jre-openjdk
[root@datafireball1 jvm]# ls -alth
total 80K
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jun  7 21:07 .
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   35 Jun  7 21:07 jre-1.7.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   27 Jun  7 21:07 jre-1.7.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   29 Jun  7 21:07 jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   21 Jun  7 21:07 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   48 Jun  7 21:07 jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.arm -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.arm/jre
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K Jun  7 21:06 java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.arm
```

Why there are so many folders for Java and which folder should I use as the Java home?

```
[root@datafireball1 bin]# which java
/usr/bin/java
[root@datafireball1 bin]# ls -alSh /usr/bin/ | grep java
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      22 Jun  7 21:07 java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can add in your `.bashrc` file:

> export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")

and it will dynamically change when you update your packages.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution tested with Fedora 26 :

```
echo "JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to find out exact path to which java executable under UNIX / Linux:

> $ which java (suppose returns /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java)

And then set path as export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java

Comment: it actually returns /usr/bin/java, should I just do `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java` ? and copy that to /etc/environment?

Comment: can you check if java -v works on your system.I guess you have to download and install JDK first.The one that you are presenting seems to be of OS.

Comment: `java -v` is not a valid command I think, but `java -version` returns `java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.4.7.0.fc20-arm u55-b13)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)`