# Set PATH and JAVA_HOME in Fedora 25

Tags: java, maven, fedora-25

Please excuse what appears to be a question answered before, but if I read 10 different posts I find 20 different responses.

I just installed Fedora 25.  I am going to be learning Java development and need to set up my environment.  I will be using openjdk and have installed java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.  I will also be using Maven.

Now I need to set my `$PATH` and `$JAVA_HOME` variables.

I tried the answer found here ([Fedora OpenJDK Set JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102816/fedora-openjdk-set-java-home))

but after adding to my .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

and then testing, I get what appears to me to be the wrong answer because I do not think there should be a /jre/ on the end

```
> echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b14.fc25.x86_64/jre/
```

So can I please ask what I should set JAVA_HOME to so that I do not need to update it with every openjdk update?

After that I think PATH is just

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

this seems like such a straightforward thing to do yet it seems to me there is much confusion.  thx

PS
also, is .bashrc even the correct place? because I see here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java) that /etc/environment would be more appropriate)  thx

Comment: If you installed openjdk from fedora repositories, you shouldn’t have to set those variables, everything should work out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

Set JAVA_HOME :

```
echo "JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Using `alternatives` to manage versions is the strongly recommended method, so this answer should be the preferred answer, unless you have a specific reason to *not* use `alternatives`. The link `/usr/bin/java` is managed by `alternatives` anyways so that is just a more complicated way of doing essentially what this answer does

Answer (score 4):

I suggest create an alias command, modifying bashrc and set `JAVA_HOME` 
 into bash_profile, this:

1. Create command in the bashrc:

   ```
   alias set-java='sudo alternatives --config java;export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::");source  ~/.bash_profile'
   ```

Save and execute: `source ~/.bashrc`

2. Create generic `JAVA_HOME` in bash_profile:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
   PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Execute the alias command

Answer (score 2):

I put the following in ~/.profile, not ~/.bashrc and I think it's the same on Fedora (I used CentOS at work and do the same):

```
export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME=$JDK_HOME/jre
```

I have to either sign out or reboot after changing .profile.

On Ubuntu, java only changed from 7 to 8 a few years ago.  I don't know why Fedora would want to put an exact version number on the java folder.  You might complain?

If Java moves around too much for you on Fedora, use a symlink.  The symlink takes affect right away, without logging out or rebooting.  On my laptop, I encrypt my home folder, so for extra speed, I put most third party tools in a /tools/ folder and give myself account access to it (`sudo chown -R myself.myself /tools/` where `myself` is my user ID).  That's where I put my maven install.  Tomcat uses a different directory name for each release, so I make a symlink like so:

```
cd /tools
ln -s apache-tomcat-8.0.38 latest-tomcat
```

Then in ~/.profile (CATALINA means TOMCAT in this example - don't ask me why):

```
# My un-encrypted Tools folder
export TOOLS=/tools
# Tomcat
export CATALINA_HOME=$TOOLS/latest-tomcat
# Maven
export M2_HOME=$TOOLS/apache-maven-3.3.9/
export M2="$M2_HOME"bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M2
```

When I upgrade tomcat:

```
cd /tools
rm -f latest-tomcat
ln -s apache-tomcat-8.0.39 latest-tomcat
```

You can use the same technique to make a `/usr/lib/jvm/latest-java`.  In fact, if you install Oracle Java (not necessarily recommended), it does exactly that, for this reason.

Yes, what you said about the path looks correct to me.  I don't put java in my path, preferring to use `$JDK_HOME`, `$JAVA_HOME`, or just calling maven.  Part of that is for security.  Part of it is to feel like I always know which version of Java I'm using.

P.S. To me, the `ln -s` syntax always looks as if the arguments are reversed.  The actual folder name goes first, followed by your desired alias/link.

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK bundled with Fedora dosen't work for me. For example IntelliJ can't use this version. In my opinion, best option is to install Oracle JDK RPM from Oracle.

JDK location:

```
/usr/java/latest/
```

To manipilate JRE use command below:

```
sudo alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, this gets Android Studio running using the Fedora provided OpenJDK and respects the distribution provided materials without a bunch of otherwise unmanaged symlinking:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following, or replace any existing examples that look similar to it:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | cut -d/ -f1-6)
```

The command basically asks for the physical path that the symlink /usr/bin/java points to (configured by alternatives in Fedora), and then says "take the first 6 fields given to you by splitting on the / character."

Note that your $PATH will already be set up correctly for use with the Fedora provided OpenJDK.

In practice, this ends up looking like:

```
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-8.fc28.x86_64/jre
```

This assumes you have at least one of the OpenJDK packages Fedora ships.  25  probably only shipped 1.8, 28 ships 1.8, 10.0.2, and 11.0.1. (if you're reading this and still using 25, it's probably time to upgrade.)

Install one of the java-*-openjdk-headless packages available to you (or one of the Oracle provided ones), and configure which one to use using:

```
 sudo alternatives --config java
```

The default on my Fedora 28 install was to use OpenJDK 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding a `tr` could work? `export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::" | tr -d "/jre/")` ?

Also, setting it in your env var will make the var independent from the sh your using. That's a great way to store It.

Comment: when I try your expression then open a shell this is printed out before a prompt is offered

"tr: when not truncating set1, string2 must be non-empty"

Comment: I totally forget that, I changed the command, it should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have Fedora available for me, so I can't investigate how Java is usually installed, but why you don't try to replace /usr/bin/java in your expression with something like /usr/bin/javac? The actual path to javac link you can get with

```
which javac
```

And read the real path with readlink. Obviously, it works if JDK is installed (not JRE).
About updating, most of Linux distros create a symbolic link like /usr/lib/jvm which is set to the correct directory and update in case of new version. For me better solution it to put this path in your bashrc.

And yes, bashrc is usually enough if you don't need JAVA_HOME to be visible to other OS users.